# tensorflow:Casting <dtype: 'int64'> labels to bool

Tags: tensorflow

I'm running the [wide and deep tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/wide_and_deep) code and without changes I get the error:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:Casting <dtype: 'int64'> labels to bool.
```

My question is: what does this mean and how does this afect other models where I want to predict more than 2 possible results?

This error appears in a situation/tutorial where the prediction is preety much a boolean, yes/no situation. But if I have labels with three possible values I think this boolean conversion will kill my results right?

What is the origin of this warning and how to avoid it so I can train a network with more than 2 possible results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered exactly the same error when using DNNClassifier. To resolve it, I need to specify `n_classes` parameter to the number of classes in your target.

The `n_classes` parameter is to specify how many classes in your target.By default, it presume there are only two classes in your target, so it convert target value to bool.

```
m = tf.contrib.learn.DNNClassifier(
        model_dir=model_dir,
        n_classes=10, # <---------
        feature_columns=deep_columns,
        hidden_units=[400,50],
        optimizer=tf.train.ProximalAdagradOptimizer(
            learning_rate=0.001,
            l1_regularization_strength=0.001
        ))
```

Comment: Can you explain more what that `n_classes` changes in this problem?

Comment: n_classes parameter is to specify how many classes in your target.By default, it presume there are only two classes in your target, so it convert target value to bool.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error when using `tf.contrib.learn.LinearClassifier` in this tutorial: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/wide

However, in my case the problem was in defining the labels tensor in the `input_fn` of the tutorial.  Previously, it appeared as follows:

```
df[LABEL_COLUMN] = (df["income_bracket"].apply(lambda x: ">50K" in x)).astype(int)
```

The fix was to change the type to bool:

```
df[LABEL_COLUMN] = (df["income_bracket"].apply(lambda x: ">50K" in x)).astype(bool)
```